# Django DateInput widget format

Tags: django, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to change the date format from *mm/dd/yyyy* to *dd/mm/yyyy* in a DateInput widget. I am trying to change the format the following way.

```
class Meta:
    model = Patient
    fields = '__all__'
    widgets = {
        'date_of_birth': widgets.DateInput(
            format='%d-%m-%Y',
            attrs={'type': 'date', 'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```

---

I noticed that if I don't include the `'type': 'date'` attribute the date is interpreted in the **correct format**, but in that case the widget isn't displayed but just a text-field. So you have to write the date manually (including /). With the DateInput widget that looks like this with *dd* and *mm* switched [DateInput widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71ZOu.png)

---

I have also tried changing the `settings.py` the following way which also didn't help.

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-GB'
TIME_ZONE = 'CET'
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py set DATE_INPUT_FORMATS as below:

```
    DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

And in your ModelForm you could do something like below:

```
    class ClientDetailsForm(ModelForm):
        date_of_birth = 
        DateField(input_formats=settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
        
        class Meta:
            model = ModelA
```

keep in mind, that formats must be defined in the forms.py and not in the models.py.

Comment: Thank you, the format is correct but that will just result in a text field. I am trying to format a DateInput widget with a pop up calendar. When I specify `'type': 'date'` the format gets overwritten by the widgets format.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was with my computer settings. I had the language set to English (US). Changing the language to English (UK) fixed the issue.